# Installing couchbase sudo pecl install couchbase

Tags: php, pear, couchbase

If you are getting this error when installing couchbase with pecl

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/couchbase/apidecl.c:26:
/private/tmp/pear/install/couchbase/internal.h:54:10: fatal error: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h' file not found
#include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>
1 error generated.
make: *** [apidecl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install  this first:

```
brew install https://github.com/couchbase/homebrew/raw/stable/Library/Formula/libcouchbase.rb
```

This saved me a day

Answer (score 2):

As you have stated, it is imperative that you install Libcouchbase (Our C driver) first.

This is stated as step 1 in the docs:

http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/current